# Change content view variable from App file

Tags: swiftui

I am a beginner with SwiftUI. As you would know, the content view is initialised in App file as shown below :

```
 var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

I would like to pass a state variable in it so that I can close a modal when called in delegate . So, I have like this :

App file

```
struct SampleApp: App {
@State var canShowModal = false
...
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(canShowModal: $canShowModal)
        }
    }
```

Content View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Binding var canShowModal:Bool
...
var body: some View {
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $canShowModal) {
                    Container()
                }
...
```

So, in content view, I can show a modal, it works fine but, the delegate function in App file receives the notification to close the modal(I think it is better I keep the delegate in app file instead of content view). I set the canShowModal boolean to false in App file but it has no effect in Content view. What am I doing wrong? Could someone please explain? thank you

I tried the @state and @Binding, it is not working

Comment: "It has no effect in content view" Does that mean your `fullScreenCover` is being shown (as if `canShowModal` was set to `true`)?

Comment: Your code works well in my tests.
 Note, your statement `...I think it is better I keep the delegate in app file instead of content view`, there is no reason to have the `@State var canShowModal = false` in your `App`, since you don't use it there, in `ContentView` is where it belongs.
 Note also, you should have `@State private var canShowModal = false`

Comment: @stoic to answer your question, yes the content view shows the modal by setting the binding to true but, if i set the canshowmodal to false on App, it does not close the modal on contentview.

Comment: @workingdog yes, your right ,there is no reason to keep it in App but, what if i keep it there, how come it works, do you mean the modal closes in Contentview?

Comment: Of course it **does not close** the `ContentView`, it is the main view
 that you see, it only close the `fullScreenCover(...)` view.
 `...how come it works`, well your code uses a `@State` variable that you pass as
 a `@Binding` to another view, that is perfectly correct, that is why it works.